# wxWidgets (C++) fails to perform many wxDC.DrawPoint() operations

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I would be very grateful for any kind of help. I develop an application using wxWidgets via wxDevC++ on Windows 7. I have a function that does some calculations and is supposed to produce a 2D colour plot of data acquired. It looks like this:

```
void draw2DColourPlot (wxDC *dc)
{
    wxBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Create (800, 400);

    wxMemoryDC *memDC = new wxMemoryDC ( bmp );

    ofstream dbgStr ( "interpolating.txt", std :: osftream :: out );

    int progress = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 800; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 400; ++j )
        {
            unsigned char r, g, b,;

            // calculate values of r, g, b

            memDC -> SetPen ( wxPen ( wxColor (r,g,b), 1 ) );
            memDC -> DrawPoint ( i,j );

            dbgStr << "Point ( " << i << ", " << j << " ) calculated" << '\n';
            ++progress;

            updateProgressBar ( progress );
        }
    }

    dc -> SetPen ( wxPen ( wxColor ( 255, 255, 255 ), 1 ) );
    dc -> Clear ();
    dc -> Blit ( 0, 0, 800, 400, memDC, 0, 0 );

    return;
}
```

The problem is, that sometimes it does not work - the progress bar reaches some value (between 10 and 90 percent, as I've observed), then everything freezes for a couple of seconds and then DC goes blank (any previous content disappears). After a few times the proper result may be drawn, but it's not a rule. In "interpolating.txt" file the last line is "Point (799, 399) calculated".

Previously I didn't use wxMemoryDC - I used dc -> DrawPoint () directly and observed the same behaviour (points were drawn as expected, but at some point everything dissapeared).

It happens more often when executing on my laptop (also W7), but sometimes on PC, too.

Do you have any solution to that? Is there a chance, that I use wxWidgets incorrectly and it should be done the different way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is due to memory/resource leaks: you allocate `wxMemoryDC` on the heap but never delete it and leaking DCs is particularly bad because they are a limited resource under Windows, so if you leak too many of them, you won't be able to create any any more. To fix this, just allocate it on the stack instead.

Secondly, while what you do is not wrong, it's horribly inefficient. For a simple improvement, set your pixels in [wxImage](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image.html), then convert it to `wxBitmap` at once. For a yet more efficient approach, use [wxPixelData](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_pixel_data.html) to set pixels directly in the bitmap. This will work much faster than what you do.